# programmatically change print setting window.print()

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I want to set the paper size, margins, scale, and use graphic images programmatically, so customers who use my program don't have to make it difficult to set the configuration.

[image: print setting image]

I have got several options such as margins and CSS using the following code, but I don't know for other configuration

```
@media print 
  {
      @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0;
      }
  }
```

Comment: You cannot programmatically set the print options. They are handled by the browser/OS based on what capabilities the attached printer has available.

Comment: So in other words let my customer have a headache to configure those settings, sorry I'm not that type of person

Comment: As annoying as it may be, you don't have any alternative.

Comment: All you can do is provide adequate instructions on your site for your customers.